# failure to sudo apt upgrade: Errors were encountered while processing /linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04, dpkg

Very inexperienced with linux so this might just be a result of cascading user error but whenever I try to run sudo apt upgrade I repeatedly get these error messages. autoremove, autoclean, removing unnecessary kernels, and fixing broken packages in recovery mode have helped a little, but haven't completely fixed this. System is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on an MSI MS-7641

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libvlc5 libimage-magick-perl vlc-data libvlccore9 imagemagick libavdevice58
  ffmpeg libopenexr25 perlmagick libmagick++-6.q16-8 libpostproc55
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libavcodec58 libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libavutil56 imagemagick-6.q16 libswscale5
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libgsl27 libswresample3 imagemagick-6-common
  vlc-plugin-video-output libavformat58 libgslcblas0 libvlc-bin
  vlc-plugin-base libavfilter7
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages have been kept back:
  python3-update-manager systemd-hwe-hwdb update-manager update-manager-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-36-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-36-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/build......(bad exit status: 2
)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.6.4.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-36-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 1
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-39-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-39-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/build......(bad exit status: 2
)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.6.4.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-39-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned err
or exit status 1
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-6.2.0-39-generic
Setting up linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (6.2.0-39.40~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-39-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-39-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-39-generic/build......(bad exit status: 2
)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.6.4.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-39-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (6.2.0-36.37~22.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.0-36-generic
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/etc/dkms/framework.conf)
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed
Deprecated feature: REMAKE_INITRD (/var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/source/dkms.conf)

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j8 KVER=6.2.0-36-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.0-36-generic/build......(bad exit status: 2
)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 5.6.4.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.6.4.2/build/make.log for more information.
dkms autoinstall on 6.2.0-36-generic/x86_64 failed for rtl8812au(10)
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error
 exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while proces
sing:
 linux-headers-6.2.0-36-generic
 linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic
 linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```